# Append both stdout and stderr to a file

Tags: bash

`>` redirects stdout to a file, and overwrites the file.

`&>` redirects both stdout and stderr, and overwrites(?) the file.

I want **append** both stdout and stderr to a file, not overwrite. I tried `&>>` but it doesn't work. Does `&>` already do what I want? If not, any other trick?

Comment: [First result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876239/how-can-i-redirect-and-append-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-with-bash) when googling [append stdout and stderr to file](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-ab&ei=UNysWp2QJYXazwL69qPwAw&q=append+stdout+and+stderr+to+file&oq=append+stdout+and+stderr+to+file&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0i5i30k1l2.48158.48158.0.48886.1.1.0.0.0.0.114.114.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.112....0.yymvpFvR-hg)

Comment: Sorry, searched only on superuser. And thanks. I was aware of `cmd >file.txt 2>&1` but it didn't strike me to try `cmd >>file.txt 2>&1`.

Comment: @user128785 You can post an answer to your own question

Comment: `&>>` should work, it's in bash since version 4.

Comment: I thought the question will be deleted. Answering now with the info you people gave.

Answer (score 6):

There are (at least) two ways of achieving this:

1. Either use this construct: `cmd >>file.txt 2>&1` where `>> file` appends the output to the file and `2>&1` redirects the `stderr` to `stdout`.
2. Or use `cmd &>>file` ensuring that you have bash version >4 (using `bash --version`) **and** `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of file (`#!/bin/sh` won't work).